# How to call a method from python class to a robot class

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a method in python file that returns a value lilke URL.
Which I want to call in robot framework to launch the test cases, by appending environment .
 Below is the code that I have used.

python and robot file code. please let me know where I am doing it wrong.
Am trying calling method from python file which returns the url into robot framework class,

```
Environment.py

class TestUrl:
  def getBaseUrl(self, env):
    if env == 'int':
        domain = 'example.com/'
        return domain


  def getFullUrlForEclaimsHome(self, env, partner):
    x = self.getBaseUrl(env)
    url = 'https://' + partner + x
    print url
    return 'https://' + partner + x

test.robot
*** Settings ***
Variables    ../../CommonTestClass/Environments.py

*** Variables ***
${browser}  chrome
${env}  int
${partner}  example
${example URL}  = call method  getFullUrlForEclaimsHome('${env}','${partner}')


*** Keywords ***
Launch the browser 
    sleep  2s
    Open Browser  ${example URL}  ${browser}
    Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: You have a file named `Environment.py` (singlular) and a robot test that tries to use a file named `Environments.py` (plural). There may be other problems, but that's definitely one.

Answer (score 3):

the name of the file and the name of the class (for my experience) should match, so if the file is called "Environments.py" your class should be called "Environments" this because once that you import it in robot framework you will call directly the method "getBaseUrl" or "getFullUrlForEclaimsHome".

Plus you are missing () on your class definition:

```
class TestUrl():
```

EXAMPLE:

My Python file called: Tree.py

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

class Tree ():
    def generate_tree (self,db_server,db_table,db_username, db_password):
        DO_SOMETHING

    def retrieve_tree_info (self,db_server,db_table,db_username, db_password, tree_ID):
        DO_SOMETHING
        return (SOMETHING)
```

MY Robot Framework File:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           YOUR_LIBRARY
Resource          YOUR_RESOURCE
Library           ../External Library/Tree.py #PATH TO YOUR Tree.py FILE

   #NOTE: If you use some IDLE (I'm using RED) it give you suggestion about the method name, in my example the IDLE call it in a bit different way than it was called in the python file
*** Variables ***
YOUR_VARIABLE

*** Test Cases ***
Create tree
    DO_SOMETHING
    ${tree}=    Retrieve Tree Info    ${db_server}    ${db_name}    ${db_user}    ${db_password}    ${tree_ID}
    DO_SOMETHING

Verify Locations tree
    DO_SOMETHING
    ${tree}=    Retrieve Tree Info    ${db_server}    ${db_name}    ${db_user}    ${db_password}
    DO_SOMETHING
```

Comment: If the class and the module names match, you don't have to specify the former in the library import, that's right - [doc reference](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-names). BTW, the parentheses in the class definition is only needed if subclassing :)

Comment: oh I didn't know about the parentheses so just to avoid mistake I used to put all the time :S tks for the tips ;)

Comment: @Carlo1585r can you give an  example on how I can call "getFullUrlForEclaimsHome" in robot class and set it  to a variable

Comment: @Mahantesh example added on the answer